# Trying to run a Command with C#

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I am trying to write a program that will automate some setup for new computers at my job.  One of the tasks is changing power options for Windows 7.  I am trying to run a command that imports a power configuration file and returns the string output which contains a GUID to a variable.  When I run the program, it does not return any value to my string.  I'm sure I'm messing something up, can someone look and help?  Here is my code:

```
if(chkPowerSettings.Checked == true && radioDesktop.Checked == true)
        {
            //Establish the path to the power configuration file
            string DesktopFileName = "WTCPowerDesktop.pow";
            string CFGFileSource = @"\\\\ops-data\\Apps\\Builds";
            string TargetPath = @"c:\\";

            //Creates the strings for the whole path
            string source = System.IO.Path.Combine(CFGFileSource, DesktopFileName);
            string destination = System.IO.Path.Combine(TargetPath, DesktopFileName);

            //Copies the file, the true will overwrite any already existing file
            System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination, true);
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo importCFG = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd","/c" + "powercfg –import C:\\WTCPowerDesktop.pow");
            importCFG.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            importCFG.UseShellExecute = false;
            importCFG.CreateNoWindow = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process runImport = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            runImport.StartInfo = importCFG;
            runImport.Start();
            string PowerCFGResult = runImport.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(PowerCFGResult);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the output is on stdout instead of stderr?

Comment: I just tried changing the .StandardOutput to .StandardError just to see if that would return me anything, and it just returned me an exception.

Comment: Why not use the option provided that allows you to pass *in* a `Guid`? I.e. generate one in your code, run the command, after it's finished you already know what the correct value is? `POWERCFG -IMPORT <filename> <GUID>`

Comment: There is no space between the `"/c"` and `"power"` in your second startup parameter. Curious why you are concating there anyway.

Comment: I just added the space, thank you for that.  However, my message box still returns nothing.

Comment: Add a breakpoint just before `runImport.Start();`, take a look at the command it is about to execute and run it manually.

Comment: I added the breakpoint and ran it step by step, what should I be looking for?

Comment: If you change the output `runImport.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`, you have to match with `importCFG.RedirectStandardError = true` accordingly. That's why you got an exception.

Comment: That is it.  It is returning an error, now I have to figure out why it is.  Thank you.

Comment: Also consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919803/,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040706/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765493/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN docs suggest waiting till the program closes after reading from the stream

```
        string DesktopFileName = "WTCPowerDesktop.pow";
        string CFGFileSource = "\\\\ops-data\\Apps\\Builds";
        string TargetPath = "c:\\";

        //Creates the strings for the whole path
        string source = System.IO.Path.Combine(CFGFileSource, DesktopFileName);
        string destination = System.IO.Path.Combine(TargetPath, DesktopFileName);

        //Copies the file, the true will overwrite any already existing file
        System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination, true);
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo importCFG = 
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("powercfg",
            string.Format("–import {0}", TargetPath))
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
        };

        System.Diagnostics.Process runImport = new System.Diagnostics.Process(importCFG);
        runImport.Start();
        string PowerCFGResult = runImport.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        runImport.WaitForExit(); //Add this line--
        MessageBox.Show(PowerCFGResult);
```

However I cannot test this myself as I do not have the application you are executing.

Update: I just noticed you used `@` and escaped strings (`"\\"`). This could also be a problem

Comment: PowerCFGResult is a string without the option to place a .WaitForExit(); after.  I tried placing a runImport.WaitForExit(); before the string declaration, and that didn't work either.

Comment: You can also try executing the command directly instead of through the command prompt.

Comment: I have tried the update and my message box still returns me nothing.  I appreciate all your help though.  Do I have the right idea for trying to output a command line to a string in this method?

Comment: I just saw your comment about executing the command directly, can you point me to a tutorial on how to do that?  I found a tutorial that showed me how to do it this way.  Sorry, I'm kind of new at this.

Comment: Yes according to the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) you have done everything correctly. I would guess something on the command side isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment... so i post it as an answer.

String with @ at the beginning does not need the double \. I'm thinking about the TargetPath variable, don't know about the previous one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried removing the not required \'s and my message box still returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to copy from a network location into C: drive, I think that needs elevated privileges to your program. try for testing purposes to copy from e:\source to e:\dest

Comment: The file copies correctly, I have verified that.  I have admin privileges, so that isn't the concern here, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store directly to C:\ but to C:\Users\Username\AppData if you do choose to write to C:\ then you may need to follow this [how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) and force administrator rights.

Comment: The file copies just fine, I am not having permissions issues for the file copy, that was one of my first concerns, but I made sure the file copied just fine.

Comment: I was really just pointing out good protest on where files should be store; the administrator link was about running a command prompt from inside a program. I do not believe it will read the file because it is located at C:\ and the command prompt is not admin level. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: ahhh... I see, I'll have to give it a try in a different location when I get a chance